# How can I set the dns servers to use from a Java program?

Tags: java, clojure, dns

I am using Ubuntu 64 bit and Java ignores the system DNS settings. How can I set these manually from within my Java program?

Here is the code (sorry the JVM language is Clojure):

```
(clojure.contrib.http.agent/string (clojure.contrib.http.agent/http-agent (str "http://yahoo.com")))
```

:which results in:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: yahoo.com
```

Other people have had similar problems:
[Java cannot resolve DNS address from AIX: UnknownHostException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967717/java-cannot-resolve-dns-address-from-aix-unknownhostexception)

```
 **nslookup yahoo.com**
Server:         192.168.1.1
Address:        192.168.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   yahoo.com
Address: 69.147.125.65
Name:   yahoo.com
Address: 72.30.2.43
Name:   yahoo.com
Address: 98.137.149.56
Name:   yahoo.com
Address: 209.191.122.70
Name:   yahoo.com
Address: 67.195.160.76
```

Comment: How do you deduce that the system DNS-settings is not being followed correctly?

Comment: Quite doubtful. Could you post a code, with which you check that?

Comment: Thanks I have posted the code

Comment: while you're at it, post the results of a host or nslookup that is contrary to what you are getting from the code.

Comment: How about some stack trace and/or error messages indicating the "unknown host" error?  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: I get java.net.UnknownHostException: yahoo.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I found the answer to my problem at:

http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=477211

lib32nss-mdsn needs to be installed on Ubuntu to make this work